# ASP.NET MVC Controller Logic - Is this too much?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was just wondering how much logic you put in your controllers? I know they are supposed to be slim, but it seems you have to put in some.

Have a look at my controller please and let me know what you would do to refractor it. Thanks!!

```
Namespace Controllers
    Public Class ShopController
        Inherits ControllerBase

#Region "Members/Properties"

        Private ProductService As IProductService
        Private UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork

#End Region

#Region "Constructor(s)"

        Public Sub New(ProductService As IProductService, UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork)
            Me.ProductService = ProductService
            Me.UnitOfWork = UnitOfWork

        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Methods"

        <HttpGet()>
        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View(New ShopViewModel With {
                        .Categories = Mapper.Map(Of IEnumerable(Of Category), IEnumerable(Of CategoryViewModel))(ProductService.GetCategories)
                    })

        End Function

        <HttpGet()>
        Function ListProducts(ID As String, CatID As Integer) As ActionResult
            Return View(New ShopViewModel With {
                        .Products = Mapper.Map(Of IEnumerable(Of Product), IEnumerable(Of ProductViewModel))(ProductService.GetProductsByCategoryID(CatID))
                    })

        End Function

        <HttpPost()>
        Function GetCartAsJson() As ActionResult
            Return New JsonResult With {.Data = ShoppingCart}

        End Function

        <HttpPost()>
        Function AddItemToCart(Model As ShoppingCartItemViewModel) As ActionResult
            Dim Item As ShoppingCartItem

            Item = ShoppingCart.GetItemBySku(Model.Sku)

            If (Item IsNot Nothing) Then
                Item.Quantity += Model.Quantity
                UpdateCartItemPricing(Item)
            Else
                Dim Product = ProductService.GetProductDetailBySku(Model.Sku)

                Item = New ShoppingCartItem With {
                    .ProductID = Product.ID,
                    .Sku = Model.Sku,
                    .Name = Product.Name,
                    .Description = Product.ChildProducts(0).Name,
                    .Price = 0D,
                    .Quantity = Model.Quantity
                }

                ShoppingCart.AddItem(Item)
                UpdateCartItemPricing(Item)

            End If

            Return New JsonResult With {.Data = ShoppingCart}

        End Function

        <HttpPost()>
        Function UpdateCartItem(Model As ShoppingCartItemViewModel) As ActionResult
            Dim Item = ShoppingCart.GetItemBySku(Model.Sku)

            If (Item IsNot Nothing) Then
                If (Model.Quantity < 1) Then
                    ShoppingCart.DeleteItem(Item)
                Else
                    Item.Quantity = Model.Quantity
                    UpdateCartItemPricing(Item)
                End If
            End If

            Return New JsonResult With {.Data = ShoppingCart}

        End Function

        Private Sub UpdateCartPricing()
            For Each Item In ShoppingCart.Items
                UpdateCartItemPricing(Item)
            Next
        End Sub

        Private Sub UpdateCartItemPricing(Item As ShoppingCartItem)
            Item.Price = ProductService.GetPriceForSkuByQuantity(Item.Sku, Item.Quantity)
        End Sub

#End Region

    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Update**

So I refactored it one some suggestions (thanks guys!). This is what I came up with:

```
Namespace Controllers
    Public Class ShopController
        Inherits ControllerBase

#Region "Members/Properties"

        Private ProductService As IProductService
        Private ShoppingCartService As IShoppingCartService
        Private UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork

#End Region

#Region "Constructor(s)"

        Public Sub New(ProductService As IProductService, ShoppingCartService As IShoppingCartService, UnitOfWork As IUnitOfWork)
            Me.ProductService = ProductService
            Me.ShoppingCartService = ShoppingCartService
            Me.UnitOfWork = UnitOfWork

        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Methods"

        <HttpGet()>
        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View(New ShopViewModel With {
                        .Categories = Mapper.Map(Of IEnumerable(Of Category), IEnumerable(Of CategoryViewModel))(ProductService.GetCategories)
                    })

        End Function

        <HttpGet()>
        Function ListProducts(ID As String, CatID As Integer) As ActionResult
            Return View(New ShopViewModel With {
                        .Products = Mapper.Map(Of IEnumerable(Of Product), IEnumerable(Of ProductViewModel))(ProductService.GetProductsByCategoryID(CatID))
                    })

        End Function

        <HttpPost()>
        Function GetCartAsJson() As ActionResult
            Return New JsonResult With {.Data = ShoppingCart}

        End Function

        <HttpPost()>
        Function AddItemToCart(Model As ShoppingCartItemViewModel) As ActionResult
            ShoppingCartService.AddItem(ShoppingCart, Model.Sku, Model.Quantity)
            Return New JsonResult With {.Data = ShoppingCart}

        End Function

        <HttpPost()>
        Function UpdateCartItem(Model As ShoppingCartItemViewModel) As ActionResult
            ShoppingCartService.UpdateItemQuantity(ShoppingCart, Model.Sku, Model.Quantity)
            Return New JsonResult With {.Data = ShoppingCart}

        End Function

#End Region

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `AddItemToCart` and `UpdateCartItem` actions require refactoring. I would move the business logic those two methods contain into the service layer. Also private methods in a controller are always stinky.

Comment: Could you see my comment above on Achim's answer please?

Comment: @Sam Striano, you could define a method on `IProductService` that will take care of this business logic. Then simply call them in the controller actions.

Comment: OK. My `ShoppingCart` is a class in the MVC application, which should probably be in my domain model so all layers have access to it? Thing is, in my `ControllerBase` I have a property `ShoppingCart` that gets filled in the `OnActionExecuting` ( i stuff it in session and get it back out there) so every controller that inherits `ControllerBase` has access to this cart, so I could have a method on `ProductService` like `AddItemToCart(Cart As ShoppingCart, Item As ShoppingCartItem)` and then pass those in from the `ShopController`?

Comment: @Sam Striano, yes having an `AddItemToCart` method on your service layer which takes the shopping cart as parameter is one way of refactoring this controller action.

Answer (score 1):

Slim does not mean empty! ;-) The following part "smells" a bit in my opinion:

```
Dim Item = ShoppingCart.GetItemBySku(Model.Sku)

If (Item IsNot Nothing) Then
  If (Model.Quantity < 1) Then
    ShoppingCart.DeleteItem(Item)
  Else
    Item.Quantity = Model.Quantity
    UpdateCartItemPricing(Item)
  End If
End If
```

I would move that probably to ShoppingCard. Looks like a violation of "tell don't ask".

Comment: I am using Dependency Injection (Newbie), and so this controller uses the `ProductService` to get information about items and their pricing etc. So I was thinking the `ShoppingCart` should have an implementation of `IProductService`, but do you know how to make the constructor injection work on an item like that? Maybe I am off track?? I am using Ninject for DI.

Comment: I dont get your question!? Why change a constructor? The cited code asks the ShoppingCart for some information, based on some sku (which is part of a model). Then it makes some decissions and works on the ShoppingCard. That logic should be moved into the ShoppingCard. The method might be called "UpdateQuantity" and might expect the model. So you don't ask the ShoppingCard for information, but tell it what to do. That's a good idea: http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask